# csv import to mysql with bash script doesn't load data but doesn't show errors

Tags: mysql, bash, csv

I am writing a small bash script that loads local csv data into a local mysql host.

This is a sample of the data :

```
Date,time,Temp,(?C),Low,alarm,1,High,alarm,1,id_machine
2021/12/24,00:00:00,17.9,0,0,9275
2021/12/24,00:00:30,17.9,0,0,9275
```

The Temp header contains a degre sign that I try to remove but I think without success, but seeing that I ignore LINE 1 in my sql script does it matter ?

Here the script that adds the last column in my csv (id_machine) and that is supposed to import values in a table called Temperature, in my database called dataprofil

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCAL_CSV_PATH="/Users/sophiabkb/Documents/DATA"
temp_file=$(mktemp)
temp_file2=$(mktemp)


for file in "$LOCAL_CSV_PATH"/*.csv
    do 
        //treatment of the csv file (adds a column and a value for each row)
        dos2unix $file > $temp_file2
        LANG=C tr -d '\260' < $file // trying to remove ° symbol
        f=$(basename $file)
        f2=${f:3:4}
        echo "$f2"
        gawk -v machine="$f2" 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="id_machine"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=machine;} 1' $file > $temp_file
        cp $temp_file $file
        //here is the mysql line that doesn't work
        mysql -uroot -prootroot dataprofil "LOAD DATA INFILE $file INTO TABLE Temperature FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES"
    done
    
rm ${temp_file}
rm ${temp_file2}

#
```

Here is the output :

```
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
bind-address                      (No default value)
binary-as-hex                     FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
histignore                        (No default value)
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              (No default value)
dns-srv-name                      (No default value)
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              0
prompt                            mysql> 
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         TRUE
socket                            (No default value)
server-public-key-path            (No default value)
get-server-public-key             FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-crl                           (No default value)
ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
tls-version                       (No default value)
tls-ciphersuites                  (No default value)
table                             FALSE
user                              root
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
compression-algorithms            (No default value)
zstd-compression-level            3
load-data-local-dir               (No default value)
fido-register-factor              (No default value)
oci-config-file                   (No default value)
```

Does anyone have an idea of why values won't import in my table ?

**EDIT**

After I shellCheck, I edited to this :

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCAL_CSV_PATH="/Users/sophiabkb/Documents/DATA"
temp_file=$(mktemp)
temp_file2=$(mktemp)

# Call 1. Uses the ftp command with the -inv switches.  
#     -i turns off interactive prompting. 
#     -n Restrains FTP from attempting the auto-login feature. 
#     -v enables verbose and progress.  

ftp -inv $FTP_HOST << EOF
user $FTP_USER $FTP_PASS
cd $FTP_FILE
mget *.csv 

bye
EOF

for file in "$LOCAL_CSV_PATH"/*.csv
    do 
        dos2unix "$file" > "$temp_file2"
                
        f="$(basename "$file")"
        f2="${f:3:4}"
        echo "$f2"
        gawk -v machine="$f2" 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} FNR==1{$(NF+1)="id_machine"} FNR>1{$(NF+1)=machine;} 1' "$file" > "$temp_file"
        cp "$temp_file" "$file"

        sed -i -e "1 { r"<(echo 'date,time,temperature,LA1,HA1,id_machine')"
d
}" "$file"
        mysql -uroot -prootroot --local-infile data profil -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE Temperature  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
    done
    
rm "${temp_file}"
rm "${temp_file2}"

#
```

But, still no import done

Comment: Put your script in https://www.shellcheck.net/, you will see some syntax issues to solve.  Major one, that actually crashes https://www.shellcheck.net/, `//` does not define comments in bash.  Use `#`.

Comment: Your header row appears to have 11 column headers, but your data has only six values. I suspect that `Low,Alarm,1` should be `Low_Alarm_1`, etc. I don't know whether this is significant if the first line is ignored.

Comment: Your script includes `echo "$f2"`, but I don't see any output that matches the assignment to `f2=${f:3:4}`. I would expect that if the degree character is still causing you a problem, then you would see it in that output. If it is NOT in that output, then you probably don't have to worry about it. But I'm having to guess (somewhat) because we don't have a working sample of your problem. Fix that code as mentioned above, and if you still have a problem, update your Q with your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Show the structure of the `Temperature` table as its complete CREATE TABLE script.

Comment: -- 27 janvier 2022 8:44:44 PM
ALTER TABLE `dataprofil`.`Temperature`
CHANGE `timestamp` `date` datetime NULL,
CHANGE `temperature` `time` time NULL,
CHANGE `LA1` `temperature` int NULL,
CHANGE `HA1` `LA1` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NULL,
CHANGE `id_machine` `HA1` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NULL,
ADD COLUMN `id_machine` varchar(255) NULL;